# Adding more information to Thread Executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

It is possible to create various type of Thread Executors in Java, `singleThreadedExecutor`, `fixedThreadedExecutor` etc.  Is there any way I can add something so that when I invoke `getThreadName()` and `getThreadID()` on an executing thread, I can see what Thread executor it has come from?

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157852/should-threads-in-java-be-named-for-easier-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You supply these factory methods with a `ThreadFactory` implementation. This is a thing that makes a `Thread` from a `Runnable`. So you can do whatever you like in the method, such as set its name, priority or daemon status -- even employ a custom `Thread` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [guava](/questions/tagged/guava), it's quite simple:

```
final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
        .setNameFormat("Fancy-pool-%02d")
        .build();
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory);
```

If you are not a happy [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) user, you can implement it yourself:

```
final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setName("Fancy-pool-" + id.incrementAndGet());
        return thread;
    }
};
```

## See also:

- [Numbering of ThreadPool in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055951)

Comment: do you really need to use an Atomic Integer there? I am not clear if the thread factory will have concurrency access or not. It is only making threads - not running them. yeah? Also surely you need to increase it each time as well.

Comment: @dublintech: I based this example on how both Guava and JDK implement thread factory. Also it's possible that two threads concurrently submit some task and suddenly thread pool needs to create two threads to satisfy growing demand. Race condition may occur. Thanks for four tip about incrementing the counter, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking about the names of the threads when the submitted tasks are running then I'd recommend using a `ThreadGroup`.  You could also use a `ThreadLocal` but that sounds more like a hack.

To use the `ThreadGroup` you would need to inject your own `ThreadFactory` to the executor.

```
final ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("someThreadPoolName");
threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadGroup, r);
        return thread;
    }
});
```

Then a thread could do:

```
String myThreadPollName = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName();
```